# reset network settings in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I just installed windows 7 on my laptop, but I can't use the wireless network connection. 
I connect to the access point but it doesn't get the right class IP. I think it is my fault, because I've said to always connect as a public network.

Do you have any idea for me to fix this problem?

many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the default network location, go to **Control Panel -> Network and Sharing Center**. Where it says your current network type, click the blue lettering and select a different type:

As shown here, the current type is "Work Network"

[image]

After clicking on Work Network you will get your choices again:

[image]